# FFmpeg. Video to images

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have [video](https://gitlab.com/dungeonlords/video-in-yuvj422p-chroma-subsampling) in MJPEG (YUV 4:2:2) format from a USB camera.

I can get all frames from my video [this way](https://superuser.com/a/1543669/1760798)

```
ffmpeg -i inFile.yuvj422p output_%04d.jpg
```

Video size is 545218B
all jpeg files size is 313704B
Why not equals?
FFmpeg change [quality](https://superuser.com/a/660792/1760798)? Should I add code like "-q:v 2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are using **re-encode** the video frames.
Add `-c:v copy` for avoid re-encoding.

Replace `ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i input.yuvj422p output_%04d.jpg` with:

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i input.yuvj422p -c:v copy output_%04d.jpg
```

---

In context, "re-encoding" means that the each video frame is decoded into uncompressed video frame, then encoded (compressed) to JPEG image format.
The process of JPEG decoding and encoding (re-encoding) is "lossy" (quality is lost), and the output images are different from the input video frames.

FFmpeg default behavior applies re-encoding (even when the input and the output are both in JPEG format).
In order to avoid re-encoding we may add `-c:v copy` argument, which forces FFmpeg to pass the input stream/frames to the output as is (without decoding and re-encoding).

---

Testing:

Building synthetic MJPEG video (used as input for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -vcodec mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj422p -f mjpeg input.yuvj422p`

Size of input.yuvj422p is 51K.

---

Converting MJPEG to JPEG images without `-c:v copy`:

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i input.yuvj422p output_%04d.jpg`

Total size of the 10 JPEG images is 44K.

---

Converting MJPEG to JPEG images with `-c:v copy`:

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i input.yuvj422p -c:v copy output_%04d.jpg`

Total size of the 10 JPEG images is 51K (same size as input.yuvj422p).